# How can I get information from my Android 10 phone with a severed screen cable?

Tags: android-10, broken-screen, motorola

I have a Motorola Moto e.  The screen has been loose for a few months, but I've been able to manage.  An ill timed flip kick from a 6 year old sent the phone flying and severed the ribbon cable.  I'm trying to transfer my number to a new phone.  I need to be able to look at a text message on the phone.  I had previously set up google messages for web, but somehow it isn't working at the moment.  I haven't fiddled with any of the debugging stuff for a while, so I suspect that won't work because I won't be able to authorize the connection because the screen doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I was going suggest trying to plug it into an external display, but it appears it has a MicroUSB port, and I don't think Motorola does any video out via non-USB-C

Comment: Well, I managed to get my main mission of proving the phone is mine to family mobile by using a keyboard, an OTG dongle, and Google Assistant to eventually get an authorization code out of my text messages.  It was not a pleasant ordeal.

Comment: Wow! That's a pretty impressive journey! I'd suggest changing the title to "get a two-factor authentication text message" from "information" and submitting an answer to your own question with this method that worked!